# Assume IAM Role for Localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, localstack

Can I Upload an Image to S3 Bucket in Localstack using IAM Role permissions? i Have tried reading secret key and id using aws credentials file, but it is throwing permission denied exception. Is there a way i can get around with this?